# Receiving System.IO.IOException when trying to delete an entry

Tags: c#, postgresql, foreign-keys, sql-delete, npgsql

I have a database with 60 tables. One is table `person` which is referenced by a large number of other tables (about 40), mostly using `ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE`.

Using Npgsql, I try running the following command:
`DELETE FROM person WHERE id = @PersonId`

As a result I receive a System.IO.Exception:

> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while reading from stream ---> System.IO.IOException: Von der Übertragungsverbindung können keine Daten gelesen werden: Ein Verbindungsversuch ist fehlgeschlagen, da die Gegenstelle nach einer bestimmten Zeitspanne nicht richtig reagiert hat, oder die hergestellte Verbindung war fehlerhaft, da der verbundene Host nicht reagiert hat. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Ein Verbindungsversuch ist fehlgeschlagen, da die Gegenstelle nach einer bestimmten Zeitspanne nicht richtig reagiert hat, oder die hergestellte Verbindung war fehlerhaft, da der verbundene Host nicht reagiert hat
>      bei System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
>      bei System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>      --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
>      bei System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>      bei Npgsql.NpgsqlReadBuffer.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<g__EnsureLong|0>d.MoveNext()
>      bei Npgsql.NpgsqlReadBuffer.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<g__EnsureLong|0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
>      bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      bei Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass161_0.<g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()

In English, the inner exception is

> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while reading from
>   stream ---> System.IO.IOException: Data can not be read from the
>   transmission connection: A connection attempt failed because the
>   remote station did not respond correctly after a certain period of
>   time, or Established connection was faulty because the connected host
>   did not respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection
>   attempt failed because the remote station did not respond correctly
>   after a certain amount of time, or the connection made failed because
>   the connected host did not respond to System.Net.Sockets.
>   Socket.Receive (Byte [] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags
>   socketFlags) at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read (Byte [] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 size) --- End of internal exception stack trace

In the Postgres logs it says:

> 2019-03-28 12:42:15.077 CET [75060] LOG:  konnte Daten vom Client nicht empfangen: unrecognized winsock error 10053

I suppose it is not a deadlock as there is no deadlock message in the logs.

I think it's related to the fact that the table is referenced by so many foreign keys. But I have no idea how to investigate further.

Comment: what is your timeout value set to in your code? how long does it take to run the query outside of code? try setting the commandTimeout value to 0 to disable timeouts

Comment: Setting Command Timeout to 0 resolved the issue. Which means that it takes about 30 seconds after the command returns. Is there any way how I can investigate why it takes such a long time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My money is on missing indexes on the foreign keys referencing `person`.

If you have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE atable (
   id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
   parent_id bigint NOT NULL
      REFERENCING parent ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

and the table contains a lot of rows, then every row deleted in `person` will result in a sequential table scan on `atable` to find the matching rows. That is probably where all your time is spent.

Create an index on all tables referencing `person`:

```
CREATE INDEX ON atable (parent_id);
```

That will make the delete much faster.

[This blog post](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/index-your-foreign-key/) explains the problem in detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't know this as in MySQL indexes on FKs are mandatory.

Answer (score 3):

Per the exception, this issue is related to a timeout of a long running script. You didn't include a code sample so I can't specifically provide the syntax to increase this but setting the `commandTimeout = 0` will disable timeout and will resolve the problem.

To address your question in the comments,

> Is there any way how I can investigate why it takes such a long time?

It could just be deleting a large amount of records. You should run your queries outside of C# to ensure queries are optimized before inserting them into code.

Deleting large sets of records can take a while, you should look into `truncate` or some other purging design such as dumping into temporary tables, etc.